# How to get all child elements using BeautifulSoup framework

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have such an HTML document and I want to get the content inside the section

```html
<body>
  <section class="post-content">
    <h1>title</h1>
    <div>balabala</div>
  </section>
<body>
```

When I use the following code

```py
soup.find_all("section", {"class": "post-content"})
```

I get

```html
<section class="post-content">
  <h1>title</h1>
  <div>balabala</div>
</section>
```

But what I want is what is inside the section, what should I do?

Comment: What do you want the data type of the output to be? A list of elements?

Comment: Print the _children_ of the section element, not the section element itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.findChildren()` method and a list comphrension:

```
import bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup("""
<body>
    <section class="post-content">
        <h1>title</h1>
        <div>part one</div>
    </section>
    <section class="post-content">
        <h1>title2</h1>
        <div>part two</div>
    </section>
<body>
                         """, 'html.parser')

els = soup.find_all("section", {"class": "post-content"})
els = [list(el.findChildren()) for el in els]
print(els)  # => [[<h1>title</h1>, <div>part one</div>], [<h1>title2</h1>, <div>part two</div>]]
```

The `soup.find_all()` call returns a list of elements and the list comprehension loops over every element and splitting it into a list of its children. `el.findChildren()` returns an iterator, so it need to be collected into a list with `list()`.

Comment: So I can get all the child elements, they are split into the array, and then I have to iterate over them and put them back together, right?

Comment: @蔡忠振 Yes. The `soup.find_all()` call returns a list of elements and the list comprehension loops over every element and splitting it into a list of its children. `el.findChildren()` returns an iterator, so it need to be collected into a list with `list()`.